# MiniBatchKMeans Parameters

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

I am trying to cluster patches of images with Sklearn's Minibatch K-Means to reproduce the results of [this paper](http://www.stanford.edu/~acoates/papers/coatesleeng_aistats_2011.pdf).  Here is some information on my dataset:

- 400,000 rows
- 108 dimensions
- 1600 clusters.

Can I get some guidance on how to set the parameters for Minibatch KMeans?  Currently, the inertia starts to converge but then it suddenly rises again and then the algorithm is terminated:

```
Minibatch iteration 48/1300:mean batch inertia: 22.392906, ewa inertia: 22.500929 
Minibatch iteration 49/1300:mean batch inertia: 22.552454, ewa inertia: 22.509173 
Minibatch iteration 50/1300:mean batch inertia: 22.582834, ewa inertia: 22.520959 
Minibatch iteration 51/1300:mean batch inertia: 22.448639, ewa inertia: 22.509388 
Minibatch iteration 52/1300:mean batch inertia: 22.576970, ewa inertia: 22.520201 
Minibatch iteration 53/1300:mean batch inertia: 22.489388, ewa inertia: 22.515271 
Minibatch iteration 54/1300:mean batch inertia: 22.465019, ewa inertia: 22.507231 
Minibatch iteration 55/1300:mean batch inertia: 22.434557, ewa inertia: 22.495603 
[MiniBatchKMeans] Reassigning 766 cluster centers.
Minibatch iteration 56/1300:mean batch inertia: 22.513578, ewa inertia: 22.498479 
[MiniBatchKMeans] Reassigning 767 cluster centers.
Minibatch iteration 57/1300:mean batch inertia: 26.445686, ewa inertia: 23.130030 
Minibatch iteration 58/1300:mean batch inertia: 26.419483, ewa inertia: 23.656341 
Minibatch iteration 59/1300:mean batch inertia: 26.599368, ewa inertia: 24.127225 
Minibatch iteration 60/1300:mean batch inertia: 26.479168, ewa inertia: 24.503535 
Minibatch iteration 61/1300:mean batch inertia: 26.249822, ewa inertia: 24.782940 
Minibatch iteration 62/1300:mean batch inertia: 26.456175, ewa inertia: 25.050657 
Minibatch iteration 63/1300:mean batch inertia: 26.320527, ewa inertia: 25.253836 
Minibatch iteration 64/1300:mean batch inertia: 26.336147, ewa inertia: 25.427005
```

The image patches I produce don't look like what the authors of the paper get.  Can I have some guidance on how to set the parameters for MiniBatchKmeans for better results?  Here are my current parameters:

```
kmeans = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=self.num_centroids, verbose=True, batch_size=self.num_centroids * 20,compute_labels=False,
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The behaviour you are seeing is controlled by the `reassignment_ratio` parameter. MiniBatchKMeans tries to avoid creating overly unbalanced classes. Whenever the ratio of the sizes of the smallest & largest cluster drops below this, the centers the clusters below the threshold are randomly reinitialized. This is what is incated by

```
[MiniBatchKMeans] Reassigning 766 cluster centers.
```

The larger the number clusters, the bigger the expected spread in cluster sizes (and thus smaller smallest/biggest ratio) even in a good clustering. The default setting is `reassignment_ratio=0.01`
which is too large for 1600 clusters. For cluster sizes of over 1000, I usually just use `reassignment_ratio=0`. I have yet to see an improvement from a reassignment in such situations.

If you want to experiment with reassignment, see if something like `reassignment_ratio=10**-4` is better than just 0. Keep an eye on the log messages. If more than 1 or 2 clusters are getting reassigned at once, you should probably reduce `reassignment_ratio` further. You may also want to increase `max_no_improvement` to make sure the algorithm has enough time to recover from the randomization introduced by reassignment, since that is likely to makes things worse at least initially, even if it gets you out of a local minimum in the long run.
Increasing the batch size may also help avoid reassignment triggering by some clusters becoming to small just from sampling variation.